# What should I put under Savings and Investments in the UK Visa application?

Tags: visas, uk, filipino-citizens

In the UK Visa application form, the question asks: Total Monthly Income from Savings and Investments. Do I put my total savings balance or the interest I receive from the savings? For example, in the Philippines, I have savings of say 1 million pesos, but this only earns very small interest of 3 thousand pesos per month. Do I write 1 Million, or do I write 3 thousand pesos?

Answer (score 7):

3,000. Or whatever the real figure is. The question asks about the income, not the capital. As an aside, most working age people in the UK and the Philippines get most or all of  their income from work (wage or salary) not from investments so this won't seem strange to the visa office.

Comment: I appreciate the answer but I was under the impression that this question on Savings and Investments would be the opportunity to show that you have sufficient savings for your trip so that you can then attach the bank statement? If I only write the interest, then wouldnt I miss the chance to show that I have financial capacity to visit UK? I have built up savings when I worked abroad a few years back, but now that I work in the Philippines I dont have as impressive a monthly income that can assure the assessor of my financial capacity. I thought the declaration on savings would help.

Comment: Is there a separate space to put the total amount of savings? If there is only a space for the balance of your current account (checking account) then you could transfer money to there but be sure to submit statements from both accounts to prove that the funds are yours and not a loan to make your finances look better than they really are.

Comment: There is no space to put the total amount of savings that's why i'm in a dilemma where In the form I can actually declare my savings so that i can prove that i have the financial capacity to visit UK.

Comment: Online form is down right now, but are you looking this question from the paper form? "5.12 Do you have savings, property or other income (for example from stocks and shares)?" It has a free text box and the comma after savings means you can write "1M PHP cash savings which provide 3k PHP interest monthly"

Answer (score 1):

You should put your interest amount only. they are asking you about your income from your saving. do not put how much savings you have. kindly mention how much you get interest from your savings.so you should put 3 thousand pesos as per your details.